# Cut out/remove certain parts of Angular CDK shadow overlay

Tags: html, css, angular6, overlay, angular-cdk

I am working on an Angular 6 project. I have created a demo mode for the application, i.e Tooltip having Next and Previous buttons. When the tooltip is active, I have attached an Angular CDK overlay to the tooltip(code below), which blurs the website. Until now, its as expected. Now, I want to highlight the element the tooltip is attached to.

**Current status:**
[image: Current Status]

**HTML**

```
<div class="widget-toolbar pull-right">
<helpcomp-button  
              id="wiki1"
              [style]="{'width': 'auto'}"
              [label]="'?'"
              [mdePopoverTriggerFor] = "wiki1"
              [classes] = "'blue-green-transition'">
</helpcomp-button>
<mde-popover #wiki1="mdePopover" mdeFocusTrapAutoCaptureEnabled="true"
             [mdePopoverOverlapTrigger]="false" mdePopoverTriggerOn="disable"
             mdePopoverArrowWidth="15" mdePopoverArrowColor="#34ebe8">
  <mat-card style="
                  background:#34ebe8;
                  color:#1f27cc;" state-step=1>
    <mat-card-content>
      <button type="button" macocoTooltip state-step=3>To Personal</button>
      <button type="button" macocoTooltip state-step=4>To Faculty</button>
      <p> sample tooltip </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button type="button" macocoTooltip>Previous</button>
      <button type="button" macocoTooltip>Next</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

How can I now highlight the element? I am trying to solve this for a day now and would really appreciate your advice. Thanks.

Comment: position  +z-index should be able to bring it up front. Have you tried it ?

Comment: yes, zIndex does work, but I suppose its not a good standard.

Comment: That is the purpose of z-index ...

Comment: yes, but to set the index value works for some element, not for some.

Comment: read the specification to understand why :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index   *The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I think accessing the cdkoverlay object from the library is better? because the library does not expose the cdkoverlay object.

Comment: the better is what you manage the best ;)

Comment: Wow, Amen, cheers to that!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you would like the "?" button to appear over the box-shadow styling?

Try applying a "position" style to the element, for example:

```
<helpcomp-button  
          id="wiki1"
          [style]="{'width': 'auto', 'position' : 'fixed'}"
          [label]="'?'"
          [mdePopoverTriggerFor] = "wiki1"
          [classes] = "'blue-green-transition'">
</helpcomp-button>
```

Comment: yes, "?" appear over the box-shadow. Let me try the solution you advised.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I basically played with the CDKOverlay object. In my case, I am using mde-popover [library](https://github.com/joejordanbrown/popover/blob/master/projects/material-extended/mde/src/lib/popover/popover.md). The library is using CDK OverlayRef object where they attach the popup TemplatePortal to the overlay.

I have changed the library code to get access to the overlay object as well the elementRef where the popover directive is placed into and set a radial-gradient.

Here is the code:

**Library code(popover-trigger.ts):**

```
/** Opens the popover. */
openPopover(): void {
if (!this._popoverOpen && !this._halt) {
  this._createOverlay().attach(this._portal);

  /** Only subscribe to backdrop if trigger event is click */
  if (this.triggerEvent === 'click' && this.backdropCloseOnClick === true) {
    this._subscribeToBackdrop();
  }

  $('.cdk-overlay-container').css('background', `radial-gradient(circle at ${this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().x}px ${this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().y}px, transparent, black)`);
  this._initPopover();
 }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Found a better way of doing it. No need to use jquery, better to use Renderer2 class.

```
openPopover(): void {
  if (!this._popoverOpen && !this._halt) {
   this._createOverlay().attach(this._portal);

  /** Only subscribe to backdrop if trigger event is click */
  if (this.triggerEvent === 'click' && this.backdropCloseOnClick === true) {
    this._subscribeToBackdrop();
  }
  this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlayRef.overlayElement.parentElement.parentElement, 'background', `radial-gradient(circle at ${this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().x}px ${this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().y}px, transparent, black)`);
  this._initPopover();
}
```

}

So, that's it. Hope this code helps somebody!!

- Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Angular CDK overlay is in a different root of the HTML, so a z-index approach to highlight the item that is behind is not possible. (Because z-index is related to their father)

My suggestion which works great for me, is to use the overlay to draw a new element on top of the one you want to highlight. And make it relative and the tutorial or info tool-tip, to be absolute against the new element.

On your HTML:

```
<helpcomp-button  
          #anchorPoint
          id="wiki1"
          [style]="{'width': 'auto'}"
          [label]="'?'"
          [mdePopoverTriggerFor] = "wiki1"
          [classes] = "'blue-green-transition'">
</helpcomp-button>

<ng-template #newElement>
  <div style="position: releative;">
    <helpcomp-button  
          id="wiki1"
          [style]="{'width': 'auto'}"
          [label]="'?'"
          [mdePopoverTriggerFor] = "wiki1"
          [classes] = "'blue-green-transition'">
    </helpcomp-button>

  <div style="position: absolute;">
    Tutorial message
  </div>
 </div> 
</ng-template>
```

On Your TS:

```
@ViewChild('anchorPoint', { read: ElementRef }) anchorPoint: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
@ViewChild('newElement') newElementTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

const positionStrategy = this.overlay
    .position()
    .flexibleConnectedTo(this.anchorPoint)
    .withPositions([
      {
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        overlayX: 'center',
        overlayY: 'center',
      },
    ]);

this.overlay.create({
  positionStrategy,
  hasBackdrop: true,
});

overlayRef.attach(new TemplatePortal(this.newElementTemplate, this.viewContainerRef));
```

See that the overlay will draw the element on the center of the anchorPoint element that you selected.

Keep in mind that the element you choose as an anchor point may have more width or height than what it uses to display, meaning you may need to query select to an element inside your viewChild element to point the center you really need.